# The unique flat connection $\nabla$ with $\nabla ^{0,1}=\overline \partial $ when betti number $b_1(X)=0$.

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry

I came across this question in Huybrechts' Complex Geometry P192 Exercise 4.3.9 and stuck.

Let $X$ be a compact Kähler manifold with $b_1(X)=0$.Show that there exists a unique flat connection $\nabla$ on the trivial holomorphic line bundle $\mathcal O$ with $\nabla ^{0,1}=\overline \partial$.

Note that for a connection $\nabla$ on a vector bundle $E$ is flat ($F_\nabla =0$) if and only if $E$ locally admits trivializing parallel sections.

Any references and suggestion are appreciated.Thanks in advance.

Comment: So what condition does $\nabla^{1,0}$ satisfy, and how might you use the $b_1(X)=0$ condition?

Comment: I am not sure on how to prove this, but I guess that it has to do with the fact that it is possible to find a kähler potential $\rho$ (the symplectic form is given by $i \partial \bar{\partial} \rho$). Another option is to note that any pair of connections differ by a matrix $A$ of 1-forms.

Comment: Dear @TedShifrin,here is my thought:The trivial connection $\nabla_1=d$ on trivial holomorphic line bundle is obviously flat.So,now,every connection has the form $\nabla=d+A$,where $A\in\mathcal A ^{1,0}(X,End(\mathcal O))=\mathcal A ^{1,0}(X)$ since $A$ cannot provide $(0,1)$-form part.With $\nabla ^2=0$,we have $dA+A\wedge A=0$,so the $(1,1)$-form part $\overline \partial A$ vanish,then yields a Dolbeault comhomology class $[A]\in H^{1,0}(X)$. 

Since $b_1(X)=0$,we have $H^{1,0}(X)=0$,because of the form restriction,$A$ must equal to $0$.So the flat connection is unique.Am I right?

Comment: This looks right to me, @Steve.

Comment: Dear @Ted Shifrin，thanks for your time，assistance and patience.